# Getting exception Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException

Tags: c#, stream, gzip

I request for gZip response in Header like :

> request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip");

In webresponse I am getting **ContentEncoding = gzip**

I don't know how to decompress gzip response with my code and when I read the string with json I getting **Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException**

What is the solution ?

```
using (WebResponse response = GetWebResponse(request))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(result);
        }
```

This is how I construct request :

```
var request = CreateWebRequest(new Uri(uri), type);

        // create request stream from arguments
        if (args != null)
        {
            string requestData = string.Empty;

            requestData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(args, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
            var data = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(requestData);
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;

            using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);                
            }                
        }

 protected WebRequest CreateWebRequest(Uri uri, MethodType type, bool IsUrlEncoded = false)
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);

        (request as HttpWebRequest).Accept = "application/json";
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        if (IsUrlEncoded)
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        else
            request.ContentType = "application / json";
            request.Headers.Add("X-Application", AppKeyData.Appkey);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AppKeyData.SessionToken))
        {
            request.Headers.Add("X-Authentication", AppKeyData.SessionToken);
        }
        request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip");
        request.Method = type.ToString();

        return request;
    }
```

Comment: Provide some more information. What is the json and what is the type parameter T

Comment: How is your request constructed, it would be helpful if you share the code around.

Comment: I have updated my question @HariPrasad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set [`AutomaticDecompression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.automaticdecompression(v=vs.110).aspx) property on your request.

```
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
```

**Update:**

You can include below line in your `CreateWebRequest` method.

```
(request as HttpWebRequest).AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
```

Comment: You can add this in your `CreateWebRequest` method, where you create the request..

Comment: @DhruvGohil I've updated answer to suit your requirement.

Comment: Thanks it works but , How do I confirm that I m getting Gzip response ?

Comment: Glad it worked to you, please mark this as answer if it fixes your problem.